# The Function of “breathing" in This Sentence

Tags: grammar

> For sometime, all that could be heard in the dim subway with its melancholy ambiance, was the sound of Joe and I breathing.

How to analyse the word "breathing" used in the sentence above? Are they trying to say "I and Joe who was breathing" or "the breathing of I and Joe"?

Comment: I would hazard to guess that it refers to the collective breathing of both Joe and I

Comment: _Breathing_ is the gerund (i.e, the verb, the predicate) of the gerund clause _Joe and me breathing_. _Joe and me_ is the subject of the clause. *Joe and **I** breathing*, by the way, is incorrect here; the subject of a gerund clause must be either objective -- _Joe and me breathing_ -= or possessive -= _Joe's and my breathing_). The gerund clause _Joe and me breathing_, in turn, is the object of the preposition _of_, and the prepositional phrase _of Joe and me breathing_ modifies the noun phrase _the sound_, and describes that sound.

Comment: Oh, and "the breathing of I and Joe" is also ungrammatical; objects of prepositions have to be objective. Also, this _breathing_ isn't a gerund; since it has an article, it's a noun, not a verb.

Comment: I wonder if this belongs on English Language Learners. This is not an obscure phrasing, so it seems like the OP is just learning English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe and the narrator are in a subway. Joe and the narrator are breathing. The subway is so quiet that the only thing that can be heard is the sound of that breathing.

I suppose you could grammatically interpret this as meaning Joe and the narrator are breathing **and** making some noise that can be heard in the subway, but the context makes it obvious that this isn't the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't ever say

> For sometime, all that could be heard in the dim subway with its melancholy ambiance, was the sound of Joe.

Contextually that means that Joe and the narrator are both breathing, and *that's* the sound (and the only sound) being heard.